# Select value within form select

Tags: javascript, forms, bootstrap-5

I want to create a form field with select, that shows additional fields when a certain field is selected.

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <label for="event" class="form-label"
    >Habt ihr schon nähere Infos zu eurem Event</label
  >
  <select id="event" class="form-select">
    <option
      value="choose"
      selected
      aria-label="Disabled select example"
      disabled
    >
      Bitte auswählen
    </option>
    <option value="no">Nein</option>
    <option value="yes">Ja</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col col-md-4 extended">
  <label for="eventtype" class="form-label"
    >Art der Veranstaltung</label
  >
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventtype" />
</div>
<div class="col col-md-4 extended">
  <label for="guests" class="form-label"
    >Anzahl Gäste</label
  >
  <select id="guests" class="form-select">
    <option
      selected
      aria-label="Disabled select example"
      disabled
    >
      Bitte auswählen
    </option>
    <option>30 - 100</option>
    <option>100 - 200</option>
    <option>mehr als 200</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col col-md-4 extended">
  <label for="duration" class="form-label"
    >Auftrittsdauer</label
  >
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="duration" />
</div>
<div class="col col-md-6 extended">
  <label for="place" class="form-label">Ort</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place" />
</div>
<div class="col col-md-6 extended">
  <label for="date" class="form-label">Datum</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" />
</div>
```

All the divs with the class ".extended" should hide, when "Nein" is selected.

I wrote that JavaScript but somehow, the selValue always only gives back the value of "choose"

```
var Extended = document.querySelectorAll(".extended")
var selObj = document.getElementById("event");
var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

console.log(selValue)

if (selValue === "no") {
    Extended.forEach(el=>el.classList.add("visually-hidden"));
}
```

I read certain posts, how to get values from select and this is what I found, but somehow it doesn't work.
I would appreciate any help, that shows me, where my mistake is.

Comment: When are you running the code? You need to run it in an event listener when the select is changed.

Comment: BTW, `selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `selObj.value`. The value of a select is the value of its selected option.

Comment: Right now I run the function as it is. How would it look like inside an Event listener?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip with the eventlistener. I could solve the problem with the following code:

```
var selObj = document.getElementById("event");

selObj.addEventListener("change", () => {
  var Extended = document.querySelectorAll(".extended");
  var selValue = selObj.value;
  if (selValue === "no") 
    Extended.forEach(el=>el.classList.toggle("visually-hidden"));

})
```